# How to draw vertical lines representing dicrete graph with ZedGraph library in C#?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Here's the code I use to draw the discrete graph:

```
private void DrawHartleyGraph(double [] values, ZedGraphControl zed)
        {
            GraphPane pane = zed.GraphPane;
            pane.CurveList.Clear();
            pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "ν";
            pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "H(ν)";
            pane.Title.Text = "ДПХ";
            PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length ; i++)
            {
                list.Add((double)i, values[i]);
            }
            LineItem myCurve = pane.AddCurve("H(ν) - ДПХ", list, Color.Blue, SymbolType.Circle);
            myCurve.Line.IsVisible = false;
            myCurve.Symbol.Fill.Color = Color.Blue;
            myCurve.Symbol.Fill.Type = FillType.Solid;
            myCurve.Symbol.Size = 4;
            pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
            pane.XAxis.Scale.Max = numOfCountsN;
            pane.YAxis.Scale.Min = values.Min();
            pane.YAxis.Scale.Max = values.Max();
            pane.IsBoundedRanges = true;
            zed.AxisChange();
            zed.Invalidate();
        }
```

I've got the picture like this:
[image: Discrete graph]

How can I draw vertical lines beginning on the X-Axis and ending in the point, representing the value of function?

---

#### Solved

Here is the found decision. You need to modify the for-cycle this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length ; i++)
{
    list.Add((double)i, values[i]);
    LineObj vertLine = new LineObj(Color.Red, i, 0,
          i, values[i]);
    pane.GraphObjList.Add(vertLine);
}
```

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer of its own? Thank you.